# Replace slashes and remove specific spaces

Tags: sql, sql-server

Have some table that contains paths of pictures within databases. What i need to do is to replace all existing slasehes: \ to those once: / for each row.

And the next thing is to remove spaces if exist within each row before and after slashes.

For instance let's take this example:

```
  \ PicsDB\Something 2015\ Somethingbla \Some thing other\ 
    img34234.jpg
```

so we got:

```
<space><space>\<space>PicsDB\Something<space>2015\<space>Somethingbla
<space>\Some<space>thing<space>other\<space><space>img34234.jpg
```

it should be changed to:

```
/PicsDB/Something 2015/Some thing bla/Some thing other/img34234.jpg
```

P.S Note spaces within strings has to stay.

Comment: Can there be only single space before or after slash or any number of them?

Comment: Any number of them (most cases should be max 1 but i have not exclude that possibility - i had bug in my program and user could write whatever so he could also put 2 or 3 spaces...) To your second comment - you right just my typo.. (corrected)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To replace backslashes:

```
UPDATE my_table SET path = replace(rtrim(ltrim(path)), '\', '/');
```

Regular expressions are not easy with SQL. If you know maximum how many contiguous spaces you might need to remove, you can try this:

```
UPDATE my_table SET path = replace(path, '    /', '/');
UPDATE my_table SET path = replace(path, '  /', '/');
UPDATE my_table SET path = replace(path, ' /', '/');

UPDATE my_table SET path = replace(path, '/    ', '/');
UPDATE my_table SET path = replace(path, '/  ', '/');
UPDATE my_table SET path = replace(path, '/ ', '/');
```

The 6 queries as shown will remove up to 7 spaces before and after each slash. *The first removes 4 spaces if there are >= 4 spaces, the next 2 spaces, and the next 1 space*. This is computationally a bit less efficient, but easier than trying to do regex in pure SQL code.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/09277/3

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LTRIM and REPLACE` function.

```
    select replace(ltrim(path),'\','/') from test
```

[SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/83c3f/5)